# SQL to return row that having same value based on column

Tags: sql, oracle

My original data look like this, where the `ID` has been ordered

| ID | StateFrom | StateTo | MH_ID | OP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 123 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |  | 456 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |  | 456 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | 3 | 765 |  |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 234 |  |
| 7 | 2 | 3 |  | 345 |

If any `ID`  that having null `mh_id` and `op_id` it's indicate that user already deleted the entry. With this,`ID 4` should be remove from the database. After I removed this row, this is my new dataset:-

| ID | StateFrom | StateTo | MH_ID | OP_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 123 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |  | 456 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 |  | 456 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 | 765 |  |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 234 |  |
| 6 | 2 | 3 |  | 345 |

Now I'm trying to select only data that having sequential statefrom and stateto. For this case,row `ID 4` should be exclude from the overall data that I'm trying to query out because it consider no longer valid as the original statefrom value is coming from deleted entry by user.

What query should I write for this requirement? Thank you in advance

Comment: Probably it can be easily solved using `lag` window function. However, your question is unclear in what should query do when there are consecutive "unsuitable" rows. Since row with `ID=3` has `StateTo=1`, should we skip all until some row with `StateFrom=1` is encountered? Provide more descriptive case please, for example imagine there is a row with `ID=4.5, StateFrom=3, StateTo=4 or 1`.

Comment: Also, the dbfiddle with prepared dataset is better than ascii-formatted tables.

Comment: SQL table or subquery has no inherent row order, the only way to guarantee ordering is to use `order by`. Please clarify how you define starting point and how you select next rows for the current one. It is unclear why `id=4` should be excluded because ID path `4 -> 3 -> 5 -> 6` seems valid

Comment: It seems you want to look at the rows in the order of their IDs, yes? Tomáš Záluský's question concerning consecutive rows is very important. Considering this, you may even have to rethink the whole approach. Imagine these rows in order: 1/4 - 2/3 - 3/1 - 1/2 - 2/3 - 3/4 - 4/1. Would you want to remove all rows except for 1/4 - 4/1? Instead of just removing the first one?Maybe you'll need a very sophisticated set of rules to determine which rows to show and which to dismiss.

Comment: Hi all, I already update my question. Yes, the next row  ```StateFrom```  must be equal to ```Stateto``` of previous row

Answer (score 0):

```
with d as
(
    select 1 ID,2 StateFrom,1 StateTo,123 MH_ID,null OP_ID
    union all select 2,1,3,null,456
    union all select 3,3,1,null,456
    union all select 4,2,3,765,null     
    union all select 5,1,2,234,null
    union all select 6,2,3,null,345
)
select *
from
(
    select *
          ,LAG(StateTo, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS PrevStateTo
    from d
) ilv
where StateFrom=PrevStateTo or PrevStateTo=0
```